# Check if mobile or not based on User Agent string

Tags: java, user-agent

One way to check could be based on the device width, but that definitely is not concrete. Are there any UA parsers/libraries to help identify this based on user agent string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to know if your device is a mobile/desktop/tablet, UADetector http://uadetector.sourceforge.net/ has a pretty nice device categorization:

> Since version 0.9.10 we support device categorization which means that
>   for instance an iPhone or Nexus 4 will be classified as Smartphone and
>   an iPad, Kindle or Surface RT as Tablet

Comment: Thanks for pointing me this library, I will give it a try.

Comment: I was able to categorize based on user agent string using UADetector:
    `UserAgentStringParser parser =    UADetectorServiceFactory.getResourceModuleParser();
    ReadableUserAgent agent = parser.parse(s);
    UserAgentType type = agent.getType();`